# Does Drupal 7 support connecting to DB using MySQLi?

Tags: database, configuration

I have tried to connect to Mysql DB using Mysqli by declaring *'driver' => 'mysqli'* inside DB array in settings.php but I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(/srv/http/my-domain/includes/database/mysqli/database.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /http/www/my-domain/includes/database/database.inc on line 1688
```

Thanks.

Comment: No, the file does not exist.

Comment: Uses PDO, better than MySQL driver and similar to mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Drupal 7 does not come with Mysqli support. It only comes with PDO based drivers for MySQL, pgSQL and SQLite.

https://www.drupal.org/node/310070

https://www.drupal.org/requirements/pdo

See the files :

- INSTALL.mysql.txt
- INSTALL.pgsql.txt
- INSTALL.sqlite.txt

to find out more about how to install using each option.

There are also many community provided solutions for connecting to other databases including [MsSQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv), [Mongo](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb) and [Oracle](https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle).

Have a look at the [Drupal modules page](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module) for more information on [database drivers](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B2%5D=im_vid_3%3A13158)

The core advantage of PDO over MySQLi is in its database driver support. PDO supports 10+ different drivers, opposed to MySQLi, which supports MySQL only.

If you are interested in the comparison between PDO and Mysqli there are many articles around including [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059).