# Is it possible to have an external script run index.php that bootstraps Drupal?

Tags: bootstrapping, external-scripts

It seems like such a simple question, and I apologize for my Drupal ignorance, but I am unable to get our Drupal contractors to accomplish what *seems* to be a simple request.  I need the below script to work without paying for a month of contracting work:

The user *will* be logged in, and of course, there *is* a valid database.  If it matters, the site is hosted by "Pantheon", and the script will also call a custom Drupal function to return a recordset.

Is this code not possible?  Am I asking something that cannot be done ind Drupal thus the endless stream of complicated files that they keep giving me?

**`root\myscript\index.php`**  (to run as *www.mysite.com\myscript\index.php*)

```
<?php
/* Check for Drupal Instance and then bootstrap to get User and Database connection */
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
global $db_url;
$creds      =  parse_url($db_url);
$db_host    = isset($creds['host'])     ? $creds['host']    : null ;
$db_user    = isset($creds['user'])     ? $creds['user']    : null ;
$db_pass    = isset($creds['pass'])     ? $creds['pass']    : null ;
$db_name    = isset($creds['db_name'])  ? $creds['db_name'] : null ;

$db = mysqli_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if(!$db){
    die('Failed! Could not open a db connection'.mysqli_connect_errno() . mysqli_connect_error());
}elseif(!$user){
    echo 'Failed! Connected to database, but did not get $user - we canNOT proceed';
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($db,true).'</pre>';
    die('Connected to database, but did not get $user')    ;
}else{
    echo "Success! User and DB are set and ready to use - we can proceed";
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($user,true).'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($db,true).'</pre>';
}
```

This (I think) is at least the start of the Drupal function that will return a recordset when the main code above is working.

```
/**
* Implements hook_block_info().
*
*/
function xyz_listofmyitems_block_info() {
    $blocks['xyz_listofmyitems'] = array(
        // The name that will appear in the block list.
        'info' => t('List of available items'),
        // Default setting.
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );
    return $blocks;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - Yes, it is possible to have an external script to bootstrap Drupal.

If Drupal is installed in the folder `[root]`, and the index.php file that you want to get working is in `[root/myscript]`, you'd first get the working directory and then call bootstrap.inc and bootstrap Drupal.

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/../includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
// do your thing
?>
```

Comment: So, this is just common-sense website/php stuff, am I right - Drupal isn't presenting some complication to stop this from working?

Comment: if you bootstrap it right, then it shouldn't give you grief. So, yeah, I guess so.

Comment: My kingdom for a Drupal programmer who thinks like you....I felt like an idiot asking the question, but it's been like pulling teeth to get this done.

Comment: I would recommend using PDO for calling DB though. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/139043/does-drupal-7-support-connecting-to-db-using-mysqli. That's if you are using D7 and above.

Comment: Tnx. I hope the code above helps you to solve your task.

Comment: I just want a basic script to run beside Drupal...certainly best practices will be in place for the real thing, but I keep getting a list of reasons that it cannot be done, and file after file of Drupal modules/functions.etc....